# How to release Active Directory confiential attributes via ADFS claim

Tags: adfs, adfs4.0

I have marked the "Employee-Number" AD attribute as "confidential" by setting it's searchflags to 128 in ADSI Edit (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/mark-attribute-as-confidential.

I've verified that Domain Admins can read it and non-admins cannot.  I've also verified that the ADFS service account is a Domain Admin.

However, if I try to release that attribute via a simple ADFS claim, it doesn't work. I've also verified that if I toggle the SearchFlags value back to 0, the claim is released as expected.

Answer (score 0):

After substantial digging, I found that the answer is to make the adfs service account a member of `BUILTIN\Administrators`.

Comment: Thats not a good idea. AD FS is designed to operate as a regular domain user account with no admin rights anywhere (be that AD or the AD FS node itself).

Comment: You should use the same article reference to grant the AD FS service account control access rights to the attribute. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/mark-attribute-as-confidential#how-to-let-non-administrative-users-see-the-attribute-data